# Require dll using string path in F#

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Is there a way to do this in F#:

```
let fakeToolsPath = "D:\tools\FAKE\tools\FakeLib.dll"

#r fakeToolsPath
```

the fake tools are on a different path depending on the build agent that builds the code, so I need to be able to set it dynamically, from an environment variable or some config file.

Comment: I don't think that will work. The way I get around is to use relative paths in my `#r`s however  that might not work for you. This is a bit of a hack, but you could say `#I @"D:\tools\FAKE\tools\FakeLib.dll"` and `#I @"C:\OtherTools\FAKE\tools\FakeLib.dll"` and finally just do `#r "FakeLib.dll"`. Ie just include wherever the dlls  might live.  Another option would be to use a bunch if `#if`s and then pass it as a compiler conditional symbol.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit hacky, but I'd consider it making the best of the situation. Overall, having build agents for the same code set up differently seems like a flawed approach (there may be good reasons for that, of course, but it's certainly not ideal), so less-than-elegant solutions in some places may simply be a price that needs to be paid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three ideas, in order of increasing hackiness - you'll be the judge which one makes most sense in your scenario:

1. In .fsx script, you can use [`__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/source-line,-file,-and-path-identifiers-%5Bfsharp%5D) to get the directory where the script is located. If your dll is always located in the same directory relative to the script, you can use that as a "hook" to get to it.
2. There's a command-line `--reference` argument to `fsi.exe` that should do what you want. If you're using `fake.exe` instead, you can use [`--fsiargs`](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/commandline.html) to pass it in (take a look at the link for details).
3. If everything else fails, create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) as a separate build step in your CI job configuration and just hardcode the path in the script.